# Checking if boolean is set to true

Tags: java, class, boolean

I have a problem where I have two classes, main and login.
login is a menu with a button to login
and when the button is pressed it should set a boolean to true.
However when i check this in my main function it doesn't do anything in the if statement.

please ignore any bad practice etc. Im just learning and exploring

login class

```
package menu;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class login {
    
    private static JTextField usr_field;
    private static JLabel title;
    private static JButton login_btn;
    private static JPasswordField pwd_field;
    private static String usr = "admin";
    private static String pass = "pass";
    private static JLabel incorrect;
    public static boolean authenticated;

  /**
   * @wbp.parser.entryPoint
   */
  public static void loginWindow()
  {
    
      
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(74, 74, 74));
      frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow]", "[grow]"));
      frame.setTitle("Login");
     
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setBackground(new Color(74, 74, 74));
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel, "cell 0 0,grow");
      panel.setLayout(null);
      
      usr_field = new JTextField();
      usr_field.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      usr_field.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 15));
      usr_field.setBackground(new Color(56, 56, 56));
      usr_field.setBounds(31, 68, 218, 19);
      panel.add(usr_field);
      usr_field.setColumns(10);
      
      title = new JLabel("JMultitool");
      title.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
      title.setFont(new Font("Sylfaen", Font.BOLD, 32));
      title.setBounds(68, 15, 170, 43);
      panel.add(title);
      
      login_btn = new JButton("Login"); 
      login_btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            char[] inputPass = pwd_field.getPassword();
            char[] appPass = login.pass.toCharArray();
            
            if (Arrays.equals(inputPass, appPass) && usr.equals(usr_field.getText()))
            {
                
                
                authenticated = true;
                
                
            }
            else
            {
                authenticated = false;
                incorrect.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
      });
      
     
            
        
      login_btn.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
      login_btn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      login_btn.setBackground(new Color(65, 65, 65));
      login_btn.setBounds(99, 126, 85, 21);
      panel.add(login_btn);
      
      pwd_field = new JPasswordField();
      pwd_field.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
      pwd_field.setBackground(new Color(56, 56, 56));
      pwd_field.setBounds(31, 97, 218, 19);
      panel.add(pwd_field);
      
      incorrect = new JLabel("Incorrect username or password!");
      incorrect.setForeground(Color.RED);
      incorrect.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
      incorrect.setBounds(53, 156, 190, 13);
      panel.add(incorrect);
    
      incorrect.setVisible(false);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setSize(310, 230);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      
  }
}
```

main class

```
package multitool;


import menu.loginFront;




public class main {
    
    
public static void startMenus()
{
    loginFront.loginWindow();
    if (loginFront.authenticated)
    {
 
        System.exit(0); // should exit if authenticated is true.
    }
    
   
}
    
  public static void main(String[] args){
      
    
    

    startMenus();
   
        

    
  }
}
```

i've tried to use a getter and setter still same effect.

Comment: I think that `loginWindow` is being returned from before the user even has a chance to press any buttons

Comment: but if i put "System.exit(0)" instead of the boolean when it checks if the username and password are correct it will close program.

Comment: eh? `System.exit(0)` closes the program, that is just what it does.

Comment: Okay I explained that horribly. Im using system exit to see if the if statements work.

Comment: The value is not set in the main thread, it is done in a callback method called by the `addActionListener` thread

Comment: when I set the authenticated bool to true in the if (arrays.equals...) it does not set. And when i refer to it in the main class if (authenticated) .... it doesn't do anything even though im setting it true in the login function. I know that the arrays.equals statement is working.

Comment: If you add `System.out.println("After login called");` to after `loginFront.loginWindow();` you will see that `loginWindow` returns immediately.  As per my first comment

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve your problem you need to use Observer Pattern by making specific communication between objects that mean any change happened in authenticated field, it will notify the main class.

You can read more about this pattern [The Observer Pattern in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-observer-pattern)

MainLogin class :

```
public class MainLogin implements PropertyChangeListener {
    private static boolean authenticated;
      public static void main(String[] args) {
            Login login = new Login();
            MainLogin observer = new MainLogin();
            login.authenticated.addPropertyChangeListener(observer);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            this.authenticated = (boolean) evt.getNewValue();
            if (this.authenticated)
                System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

PCLauth class:

```
public class PCLauth  {

    private boolean authenticated;
    private PropertyChangeSupport support;

     public PCLauth () {
         support = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
     }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener pcl) {
        support.addPropertyChangeListener(pcl);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener pcl) {
        support.removePropertyChangeListener(pcl);
    }

   public void authenticate(boolean state) {
        support.firePropertyChange("authenticated", this.authenticated, state);
        this.authenticated = state;
   }
```

Login Class:

```
 public class Login {
    
        private  JTextField usr_field;
        private  JLabel title;
        private  JButton login_btn;
        private  JPasswordField pwd_field;
        private  String usr = "admin";
        private static String pass = "pass";
    
        public  PCLauth authenticated;
    
        public Login() {
            this.authenticated = new PCLauth();
            buildGui();
        }
    
        /**
         * @wbp.parser.entryPoint
         *
         *
         */
    
    
        private  void buildGui()
        {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.weightx = 0.5;
            c.weighty = 0.5;
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 0;
    
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
            frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(74, 74, 74));
            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            frame.setTitle("Login");
    
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout( ));
            panel.setBackground(new Color(74, 74, 74));
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
            JLabel username = new JLabel("User name");
            panel.add(username, c);
            c.gridx++;
            usr_field = new JTextField();
            panel.add(usr_field, c);
            usr_field.setColumns(10);
    
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 1;
    
            title = new JLabel("password");
            panel.add(title, c);
    
    
            c.gridx++;
    
            pwd_field = new JPasswordField();
    
    
            panel.add(pwd_field, c);
    
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 4;
    
            login_btn = new JButton("Login");
            login_btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    char[] inputPass = pwd_field.getPassword();
                    char[] appPass = Login.pass.toCharArray();
                    if (Arrays.equals(inputPass, appPass) && usr.equals(usr_field.getText())) {
                        System.out.println( SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()  + ", " +Thread.currentThread().getName());
    
                        authenticated.authenticate(true);
    
                    }
                    else {
                        authenticated.authenticate(false);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Obs,your username or password is incorrect!");
                    }
                }
            });
            panel.add(login_btn, c);
            frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setResizable(false);
    
        }
    }
```